# ffmpeg join two mp4 videos one after another

Tags: java, join, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I've got 2 videos I want them to join into one video using ffmpeg. I am running these commands in Java so I need it to use the command line so no other programme solutions apply. I have tried many different ways but non seem to work. So i got a video of 35 seconds and one of 5 seconds I need a output of 40 seconds this never seems to happen. if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found a solution to this myself and I believe this could be useful for other people as it took me a lot of time to find it. You can not join two mp4 together through ffmpeg. You can however convert the videos to a .ts file then join them one after another and convert it back to a mp4. This sounds complicated but the ffmpeg is pretty simple.

```
ffmpeg -i vid1.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb  vid1.ts
ffmpeg -i vid2.mp4 -c copy -bsf h264_mp4toannexb  vid2.ts
ffmpeg -i "concat:vid1.ts|vid2.ts" -c copy output.mp4
```

So the first 2 lines convert the videos to a .ts file and the 3rd line joins them and makes a .mp4 and obvously you can delete the .ts files if you are running this in a programming language like java.

Hope someone finds this useful as I spent a greqat deal of time trying to find this solution.

Comment: Hi, all this 3 commands will run at same time? Can you share few code if possible?

Answer (score 3):

There are different approaches with different formats, but for mp4 videos **where the videos are encoded the same way** you can concat  files using the 'concat' option in ffmpeg:

Create a text file with the full path to each file you want to concatenate - so it looks like this when you are done:

```
file '/yourdirectory/yourotherdirectory/yourVideo1.mp4'
file '/yourdirectory/yourotherdirectory/yourVideo2.mp4'
```

Call the file something like myVideosToJoin.txt (or whatever name you want) and now invoke the following ffmpeg command:

> ffmpeg -f concat -i myVideosToJoin.txt -c copy joinedVideo.mp4

Note: in case the bit in bold in the first line above is not clear - mp4 is a container for video and audio streams, and the video streams can be encoded in different formats using different encoders, different bit rates etc. This method works for mp4 files in which the videos are encoded in the same way.

Comment: you'll find that this method does not work with mp4 files

Comment: Actually it does (I've used it) but the videos need to be encoded the same way, which is a good point and should be pointed out - I'll a note to clarify this.